# Is this Homebrew cantrip balanced? Nature’s bounty

Tags: dnd-5e, druid, ranger, homebrew-review, cantrips

I made a home brew spell and I want your opinion on how powerful it is

Nature’s bounty

1d4 healing

Casting time: 1 action

Range: touch

Duration: instantaneous

Components: v s

Classes that know: Druid, Ranger

The user calls upon the spirits of nature and touches one willing creature, the target then heals 1d4 (plus spell casting mod) hitpoints. The target then gets a bonus equal to your Druid/ranger level to their next attack.

Comment: Please take a look at this meta question on [how to ask a good homebrew](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8121/how-can-i-ask-a-good-homebrew-review-question). Can you let us know what level the spell is and also go through the process in the meta? I'd also be very wary about homebrewing before you've got a good grasp on the overall mechanics and spells, but that's just my .02. Please also note that this should include your own assessment on if you think it's balanced and highlighting anything you think may be problematic to show you've put some effort into this.

Comment: Along with what NautArch has suggested it would be great to know what led you to the decisions you've made about this spell: why is it a Druid/Ranger spell, what does it do that previous spells did not do, why does it use your Druid/Ranger level instead of your general level. I'm also personally wondering: how long does the benefit to their next attack roll last?

Comment: That’s a great comment @Medix2 thank you for the feedback

Comment: If you find that a basic guideline would help you in your homebrewing efforts, I summarize the one I use in [this answer to "Are there rules on how to research and create new spells?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/166947/are-there-rules-on-how-to-research-and-create-new-spells/167418#167418).

Comment: Thanks a ton @aaron9eee because I’ve been in the mood to make a good homebrew spell ( it this one) and that’s a great help

Comment: I had a decent revision, but just gave up on it because, even though it was much worse then the original design power wise, it was still a healing cantrip, thank you for that though @Senmurv

Comment: @Senmurv: [Don't answer in comments (including partial or speculative answers).](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments)

Comment: It sounds like this is dead, but for future reference: Rangers don't get cantrips.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

## It is incredibly overpowered

There are no cantrips that provide healing. And definitely none that also give a bonus modifier to an attack roll. Giving completely free healing would allow characters to completely heal without any cost outside of and in between encounters.

The Dungeon Master's Guide (page 284) explicitly states that:

> A cantrip shouldn't offer healing.

The closest is *spare the dying* which stabilizes and *true strike* which gives you advantage on your next attack, but you have to basically wait a round.

Normally, I'd prefer to wait until your homebrew is complete, but this can be answered as-is. But when you work on it, please make sure to include everything in your next version.

Some spells to compare against would be *healing word*, *cure wounds*, and *bless* when developing your next version.

Comment: How about some kind of recoil on use? @NautArch

Comment: @Straightupoof Until you've got a better description of what your goals are for this spell and why you want to homebrew it, I don't think I can provide any help. If you're still at the brainstorming phase, hoping into our very own [chat] may help you out.

Comment: Alright, I have a good idea of a more balanced spell, but I don’t know if I should like, post an entire new question, or to put it in an answer. Where should I post the revision? @NautArch

Comment: @Straightupoof please read that meta on how to ask, it covers the revision process.